# I can't open sumo-gui (sumo 0.12.3,Ubuntu12.4)

Tags: ubuntu, simulation

I have installed SUMO 0.12.3 in Ubuntu 12.04(64 bit).
There was no error information appeared,and I created a TCL file successfully.
But nothing was returned(gui of sumo didn't open) after typing sumo-gui in terminal.
I will appreciate if anyone can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are different reasons why this could happen. I assume you compiled sumo yourself.

You should have a look at the output of configure (configure.log) whether the GUI was enabled at all. If you do not have the development package of the fox toolkit installed (it is called something like fox-devel), the GUI will not be build. If it was enabled and you have a sumo-gui executable file in your bin dir, there may be a problem with your OpenGL drivers. Try to run glxinfo or glxgears and look for warnings there.

PS: Please do not use such outdated versions of sumo.
PPS: You can always ask the mailing list for help: http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Contact